# How to handle System.AccessViolationException when i run my application as Service

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, windows-services, .net-4.5

Actually iam working on OpenCV. i had created two application one is windows form application and other is window service both the application contains same code.
everything is working fine when i run it as windows application. when iam trying to run it as an Windows service it throwing the exception.

i had googled for this exception they are saying it will occur bcz lack of memory management.how can i overcome this exception.

```
 Application: DSG Service.exe
 Framework Version: v4.0.30319
 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
 Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
 at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CvCascadeClassifierDetectMultiScale(IntPtr, IntPtr,IntPtr, Double, Int32, Int32, System.Drawing.Size, System.Drawing.Size)
 at       Emgu.CV.CascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(Emgu.CV.Image`2<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gra  y,Byte>, Double, Int32, System.Drawing.Size, System.Drawing.Size)
 at DSG.Service.ReadMyFace.Timer_Frame_Grabber_Tick(System.Object,System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
 at System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(System.Object)
 at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(System.Object)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
 at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
 at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
 at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
 at System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback()

Faulting application name: DSG Service.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x56fca95e
Faulting module name: opencv_objdetect2410.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x547df585
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00028768
Faulting process id: 0xd40
Faulting application start time: 0x01d18b06f8432dbd
Faulting application path:      E:\Amit\Projects\DSG\DotNetClient\DSG.Application\DSG Service.exe
Faulting module path:   E:\Amit\Projects\DSG\DotNetClient\DSG.Application\x86\opencv_objdetect2410.dll
Report Id: 388a222d-f6fa-11e5-96cb-fcaa14a29764
```

Comment: Is it trying to do anything GUI-wise?

Comment: No it's a windows service we are doing nothing GUI-wise... :(

Comment: This can be the bane of Windows Services - things work fine outside of a service but play up whilst as a service.  I see references there to  `Emgu.CV.Image`, does OpenCV support Windows Services do you know?

Comment: Yeah its working fine as windows service also but some times its giving me System.AccessViolationException.